# Why does iTunes not recognise a plugged in iPhone on Windows 8.1?

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows

I have iTunes 11.0.4.4 and have just installed Windows 8.1 - iTunes seems to work ok, but when I plug the iPhone in (iOS 6.1.4) it doesn't appear and be recognised.

The OS sees the phone and I can copy files from it, but iTunes doesn't react to it.

Are there any known issues with Windows 8.1 - am I paying the price for being on the bleeding edge?

Answer (score 2):

This technique just worked for me on 11.1.3.8 (it broke on the Windows 8 to 8.1 upgrade):

1. Control Panel, uninstall "iTunes" and "Apple Mobile Device Support"
2. Plug out your iDevice(s)
3. Reboot (might be unnecessary, but Windows 2.0 trained me to do this all the time after driver changes)
4. Run the iTunes installer (you might already have downloaded it)
5. Plug in your iDevice(s)

At this point, my iPod and iPad were recognized and synced.  My library appears to be intact as well.

I subsequently rebooted and these devices are still found.

Answer (score 2):

I have a permanent fix for this. The Apple Mobile Device USB Driver has to be reinstalled for Windows 8.1. To do so…

1. Plug in your device.
2. Open Device Manager (Control Panel → Hardware and Sound → Device Manager) and expand "Other Devices", "Portable Devices" or "Imaging Devices".
3. Right click on any selection that recognizes and iPod or iPhone and select "Update Driver Software".
4. Allow it to search for the driver software itself and the Apple Mobile Device USB Driver will be reinstalled under "Universal Serial Bus controllers".

After installing and without ever unplugging your device, iTunes will then recognize your device. My iPod Classic 160 GB is now synching for the first time since the update!

Answer (score 0):

deleting and re installing will fix it long enough to sync and then its gone again. I have had so many issues with 8.1 I don't know where to start. Most are the fact that the 8.1 install took off most of my dell XPS 12 drivers

Answer (score 0):

After spending another couple of hours trying to resolve this, I came up with, if not a permanent solution, certainly something which worked at least once.

- unplug the iPhone
- exit iTunes
- open up the 'Services' list and stop the Apple Mobile Device service
- restart iTunes

If you refresh the Services list you'll probably notice that the Apple Mobile Device has been restarted by iTunes.

Now plug in the iPhone and it now recognises the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

THe 64 bit driver for Apple Mobile Devices is not safe code for Windows 8.1.

Microsoft didn't release the development kit for 8.1 until it was released.

You have to wait for Apple to update Itunes 11.1 with a re-written driver.

Steelseries has a similar problem with their Mice driver's causing constant reboots on 8.1.

SteelSeries Engine for Windows
OS: Win XP, Win Vista, Win 7, Win 8 (ALERT: not compatible with Win 8.1) (32/64 bit bit).

Also Avast didn't have a Windows 8.1 capable antivirus until 8.1 was released.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Windows 8.1 and iTunes 11.1.3.8. The iPhone connected fine before trying to update it to 7.03 from 6.1.3 but iTunes required an update before I could update my phone. So I installed the new iTunes and the iPhone would not connect to iTunes but still connected fine in Windows Explorer.

What finally worked (after other failed attempts) was:

- I downloaded WinRaR and then opened the iTunes.exe installer in WinRaR.
- I then found the Apple Mobile Device.MSI file and double clicked it to install. It asked if I wanted to repair it or uninstall it and I proceeded to un-install the Apple Mobile Device application.
- Then I had to go and double-click it again to re-install it.
- Once it was reinstalled I opened iTunes and then connected my iPhone and all was good.

But now trying to update my iPhone to 7.03 and I get an iTunes error 1667, so the fun continues. I will likely use my Win7 Laptop to update to 7.03.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a [support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1538) describing the steps you can take to solve the problem:

- update iTunes
- check/replace the USB cable
- verify that Apple Mobile Device Support is installed
- restart the Apple Mobile Device Service
- verify that the Apple Mobile USB Driver is installed
- check for third-party software conflicts

Answer (score -2):

Finally. A solution that worked for me.

http://www.technipages.com/itunes-fix-iphone-or-ipod-not-detected-in-windows

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. And how does the solution recommended on the linked page differ from several answers already given?

Answer (score -3):

go to itunes properties and in compatibility tab click chang settings for all users and the choose run program as admin under priviledge level and apply

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the necessary steps and why this solves the problem?