# How do I get iTunes to see my iPhone 4S on Windows 8.1?

Tags: itunes, iphone, windows

When I connect my iPhone 4S to my Windows 8.1 laptop, iTunes doesn't see the phone.  I can browse the DCIM folder via Windows Explorer, but iTunes doesn't see the device.

Which is particularly unfortunate for me, as I don't have a Windows 7 PC to try and although I've been told that the phone has (just) been unlocked from the network, I think I have to sync it with iTunes in order for the phone to apply the unlock... is that right?

Is there some work around for this?

Comment: After posting my question, I found that this question has already been asked http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97851/why-does-itunes-not-recognise-a-plugged-in-iphone-on-windows-8-1.  The device manager answer worked... except since my registration is too new on this website, I can't mark this as a duplicate question, up vote the answer that worked for me, or comment there either.  Feeling hard done by... but at least I got my iPhone talking to iTunes :).